# Return the value checked for in a ternary condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Is it possible for the following to happen. So basically I want to check if `a` exists or is defined or is not 0 and return that value if it is so else return 0. Is it even possible as a single statement - I am not looking to use a spare variable.

```
console.log(a ? a : 0)
```

Hi! as people in the comments have been kind enough to point out. **My question is that - is there any way to simplify the above expression. I do not want to use the variable a twice. For this reason you can assume a to be a long executing function that returns a number. So, I want to use a only once**

Comment: what's wrong with your current statement? did you tried to run it?

Comment: Have you even tried executing your guess?

Comment: Hi! I have run it. But I want a simpler expression

Comment: I will edit with a new update. Sorry

Comment: @ScottMarcus you have an answer?

Comment: I think the code you have is the answer. It works and it's compact.

Comment: But it is not efficient considering that is a function that takes quite a bit of processing. Anyway thank you. No issues. It was my mistake not to put up the whole question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```js
console.log(a || 0);
```

The `||` operator coerces the left operand (a) to `boolean` type and returns it if it's `true`. Otherwise returns the right operand (0).
**Note** that if a is an empty string it will also return 0.

#### Alternatively:

```js
console.log(a ?? 0);
```

The [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??` is a recent feature that testing the left operand (`a` in this case) for being **neither** `undefined` **nor** `null` and returns it. Otherwise returns the right operand (`0` in this case)

Comment: …although depending on the use case, `a ?? 0` might be better

Comment: Hi! Amit looks like something that might be of use. I shall try it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Bergi you are right because he wants to return zero. Nice!

Comment: @Bergi can you please mention the use case you had in mind for `a ?? 0` I do not understand that expression. Might be useful down the road. Thanks.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am just trying to help

Comment: Hey Amit. Your method works perfectly fine. I have marked it as an answer. But I do not understand Bergi's method. If you can explain it it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @RohanAsokan I edited my answer check it out

Comment: @RohanAsokan hey it is nullish coalescing operator [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#using_the_nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: Yes, of course we know you are trying to help. But another way to help is to post a comment and keep our site focused on what it was designed to be for.